# Creting table named as one of "key word" in sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem I need to create table in database SQLite in Android where name of table is for exapmle ORDER where order is key word is it even possible to do it with alias or prefix or whatever else?

Comment: Why you want to use this name? just use PORDER for product order or anything.

Comment: Because I'm receving model of database in XML file from server side ant than I need to buid database according to that file which is parsed to Java Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a prefix to avoid complications, e.g. `my_order`.

You could also use quotes to force it to be recognized as identifier (see [SQLite keyword documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)).